# Error with index. index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, numpy

When I run my code I get the error

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 on line 42 for v[0]=v0.

I'm not familiar with python and don't know how to debug this.

```
""" Density at height y """
def rho(rh, y):
rho = rh*math.exp(-y/7249)
return rho

""" Acceleration of skydiver """
def accl(m, g, rho, v, As, Cs, Ap, Cp):
if y[i+1] >= 1200:
    accl = (1/(2*m) * rho(rh, y) * v**2 * As * Cs - g )
else:
    accl = (1/(2*m) * rho(rh, y) * v**2 * (As * Cs + Ap * Cp) - g)
return accl

h0 = 4000 # initial hieght
dt = 0.1 #timestep
n  = int(180/dt)
#lists for displacement, time, and velocities
v= np.array([])
v[0] = v0
t= np.array([])
t[0] = t0
y= np.array([])
y[0] = h0

#calculation of time, velocity and displacement
for i in range(n):
t[i+1] = t[i] + dt
v[i+1] = v[i] + accl(m, g, rho, v[i], As, Cs, Ap, Cp) * dt
y[i+1] = y[i] + v[i+1] * dt
if y[i+1] < 0:
    #ends plot once skydiver has landed
        break
# Plot
plt.plot(t, y, label = 'Position m')
plt.plot(t, v, label = 'Speed m/s')
plt.plot(t, accl, label = 'Acceleration m/s^2', color = 'green')
plt.xlim([t[0], t[-1]])
plt.xlabel("Time (seconds)")
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy arrays created from empty lists can't be indexed - they don't have any elements to index into.

```
np.array([]).shape
# (0,)
```

If you know the dimensions of `v` in advance, you can use `np.empty()`:

```
n = 10
np.empty(n, dtype=float)
# array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Alternately, just initialize `v` with `v0`:

```
v = np.array([v0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
v= np.array([])
v[0] = v0
```

This makes no sense: you are trying to set a value to the first element of an empty array (which has no element!).

Try this instead: `v = np.array([v0])`

if you want to grow your array, do this:

```
v = []
# whatever logic to grow v like:
for i in range(10):
    v.append(2*i-1)
# now turn it into an np.array:
v = np.array(v)
```

Comment: This will produce an error when he is accessing further indices of v. He needs to initialize v with size n.

Comment: @wit221 No: `list` do not need a size to be predefined.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to your solution to use v = np.array([v0]). This will produce an error when accessing the numpy array in v[i+1] = v[i] + ...

Answer (score 1):

Replace `v = np.array([])` with `v = np.zeros(n+1)`. Your cannot access elements of the numpy array that are outside of its bounds. Your declaration creates an empty numpy array.